# Why does the RDM6300 not read RFID tags anymore?

Tags: raspbian, python, pi-3, rfid

I've previously used the RDM6300 with the Raspberry Pi 1 and it worked flawlessly. After switching to the Raspberry Pi 3 it won't read RFID tags anymore.

I'm certain I've connected everything correctly and the module is running. I've also edited config.txt (added `enable_uart = 1`) and cmdline.txt (removed `console=serial0,115200`).

The python script I use looks as follows:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# coding=utf-8

import serial

# This is where I read the RFID tag

def read_rfid():
    ser = serial.Serial("/dev/ttyAMA0")
    ser.baudrate = 9600
    daten = ser.read(14)
    ser.close()    
    daten = daten.replace("\x02", "" )
    daten = daten.replace("\x03", "" )
    return daten

id = read_rfid()
print id
```

That's all I needed to get the script working on my old Pi 1. What changed from Pi 1 to Pi 3? What additional changes do I have to make?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`/dev/ttyAMA0` is connected to Bluetooth.

Try `/dev/serial0` (assuming this is connected to the Pi serial port) `console=serial0,115200` should have given a hint.

You can check which devices are available in `/dev/`

Comment: Bear with me here, because I'm sure if I'm doing this right. I tried using /dev/serial0 instead of /dev/ttyAMA0, but it tells me that no such directory exists. When I try /dev/tty[1-61] I'm getting "permission denied". Am I misunderstanding something here?

Comment: Check that `/dev/serial0` exists. If you literally had `enable_uart = 1` this may explain the reason it would not. Ideally you should use `raspi-config` to enable, rather than manually editing. See [How-do-i-make-serial-work-on-the-raspberry-pi3](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/45571/8697) for more detail.

Answer (score -1):

I have encountered the same problem when using a RPi 3B+ - changing the port to `//dev/ttyS0` worked for me (yes, double `//` in front of the `dev`).